# xcodebuild : No profile for team 'XXXXXX' matching 'XXX XX XX' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'XXXXXX/XXX XX XX'

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, xcodebuild, fastlane

i try to build iOS app using Fastlane in the azure deveops pipeline and i keep getting error this is the command line i can see it invoking :

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace myapp.xcworkspace -scheme myapp -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-22/app_2020.1.4.xxx.1.1.0.24_SPRINT_12\ 2020-09-22\ 13.05.54.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/myapp-myapp.log | xcpretty
error: No profile for team 'xxxx' matching 'XXX XX XX' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'xxxx/XXX XX XX'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
no rule to process file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/myapp/xxx/zAFNetworking/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
no rule to process file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/myapp/xxx/zAFNetworking/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

my question is how can i test the OS which profile team installed and why it can't be found the matching provisioning profiles

**UPDATE**

```
pipeline :
# Xcode
# Build, test, and archive an Xcode workspace on macOS.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute the app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS 10.14'
parameters:
  - name: Folderpath
    type: string
    displayName: 'configure path'
  - name: FolderCompile
    type: string
    displayName: 'Compile ios productes path'
  - name: projectName
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios projectName'
  - name: appIdentifier
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios appIdentifier'
  - name: versionNumber
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios versionNumber'
  - name: buildNumber
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios buildNumber'
  - name: plistFileFtpBasePath
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios plistFileFtpBasePath'
  - name: fastlaneAppleSession
    type: string
    displayName: 'ios fastlaneAppleSession'
    
  
    
variables:
  scheme: ''
  sdk: 'iphoneos'
  configuration: 'Release'
  CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD: xxxx
  FASTLANE_PASSWORD: xxxx 
  FASTLANE_SESSION: '${{parameters.fastlaneAppleSession}}'
  
jobs:
- job: self_hosted_connect
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool: Default

  steps:
  
  
    
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.Folderpath}}'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      artifactName: 'ios_artifacts'

- job: mac_agent
  dependsOn: self_hosted_connect   
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
 
  
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS 10.14'
 
 
  - task: UseRubyVersion@0
    inputs:
     versionSpec: '>= 2.4'
     addToPath: true
  
 
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'ios_artifacts'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
  
  
  - script:  |
   
     
     gem install --no-document bundler
     bundle update --bundler
     bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
     gem install --no-document fastlane
     
     mkdir fastlane
     mv Fastfile fastlane
     mv Appfile  fastlane
     
     
    
     pod deintegrate     
     gem install cocoapods     
     pod install     
     pod --version           
     
     fastlane release --verbose projectName:${{parameters.projectName}} appIdentifier:${{parameters.appIdentifier}} versionNumber:${{parameters.versionNumber}} buildNumber:${{parameters.buildNumber}} plistFileFtpBasePath:${{parameters.plistFileFtpBasePath}} ArtifactsDirectory:$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)

    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts'
    displayName: 'create_keychain'
 
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'Artifacts'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
      
- job: copy_back_files_to_self_hosted_connect
  dependsOn: mac_agent 
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool: Default
  steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'Artifacts'
        itemPattern: '**/*.ipa|manifest.plist'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        Contents: '**/*.ipa|manifest.plist'
        TargetFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.FolderCompile}}'



2020-09-22T13:32:41.7045300Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.70]: [32m-----------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.7046170Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.70]: [32m--- Step: create_keychain ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.7046920Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.70]: [32m-----------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8099280Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.80]: [36m$ security list-keychains -d user[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8226770Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: â–¸ [35m"/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db"[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8229590Z WARN [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: [33mFound keychain '/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db' in list-keychains, adding to search list skipped[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8234630Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8235720Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: [32m--- Step: import_certificate ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8236480Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.8239110Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.82]: [36m$ security import xxxxx.p12 -k '/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db' -P xxxxx -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/security -T /usr/bin/productbuild[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9149380Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.91]: â–¸ [35m1 identity imported.[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9285240Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.92]: Setting key partition list... (this can take a minute if there are a lot of keys installed)
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9286650Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.92]: [36m$ security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k xxxxx /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db 1> /dev/null[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9648450Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.96]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9658030Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.96]: [32m--- Step: import_certificate ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9659790Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.96]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:41.9660960Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:41.96]: [36m$ security import xxxxx.cer -k '/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db' -P '' -T /usr/bin/codesign -T /usr/bin/security -T /usr/bin/productbuild[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0123440Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: 'xxxxx.cer' is already installed on this machine
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0128380Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0136760Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: ~/Library/Keychains/xxxxx
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0145120Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: ------------Values from request ----------------
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0152440Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: project_name: xxxx
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0161070Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: app_identifier: com.xxxx.xxxx
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0167900Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: v_num: 2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0175230Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: build_number: SPRINT_12
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0182690Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: ftp_path: http://xxxx.xxxx.com/release/xxxx/ios
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0190080Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: ArtifactsDirectory: /Users/runner/work/1/a
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0197340Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: [32m--------------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0198180Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: [32m--- Step: increment_version_number ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0198960Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: [32m--------------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:42.0200360Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:42.01]: [36m$ cd /Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts && agvtool what-marketing-version -terse1[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:44.9023170Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:44.90]: â–¸ [35m3.0.2[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:44.9029580Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:44.90]: [36m$ cd /Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts && agvtool new-marketing-version 2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.1990530Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.19]: â–¸ [35mSetting CFBundleShortVersionString of project xxxxx to:[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.1993500Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.19]: â–¸ [35m2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24.[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2097780Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.20]: â–¸ [35mUpdating CFBundleShortVersionString in Info.plist(s)...[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2269250Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.22]: â–¸ [35mUpdated CFBundleShortVersionString in "xxxxx.xcodeproj/../xxxxx/Info.plist" to 2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2281080Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.22]: [32m-------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2281910Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.22]: [32m--- Step: update_info_plist ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2282830Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.22]: [32m-------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2496680Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.24]: [32mUpdated xxxxx.xcodeproj/../xxxxx/Info.plist ðŸ’¾.[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2508420Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.25]: [32m-----------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2509270Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.25]: [32m--- Step: update_app_identifier ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.2510090Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.25]: [32m-----------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.3861310Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.38]: [32mUpdated xxxxx.xcodeproj ðŸ’¾.[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4348840Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.43]: [32m------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4349750Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.43]: [32m--- Step: sigh ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4350440Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.43]: [32m------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4410530Z 
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4435180Z +-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4436040Z |                      [32mSummary for sigh 2.160.0[0m                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4437460Z +-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4437870Z | username                            | xxx@xxxx.com       |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4438240Z | app_identifier                      | com.xxxx.xxxx |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4438620Z | team_id                             | 8E6XXXXXX                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4439020Z | adhoc                               | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4439400Z | developer_id                        | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4439760Z | development                         | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4440280Z | skip_install                        | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4440680Z | force                               | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4441050Z | ignore_profiles_with_different_name | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4441470Z | skip_fetch_profiles                 | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4441830Z | skip_certificate_verification       | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4442210Z | platform                            | ios                          |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4442570Z | readonly                            | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4442940Z | fail_on_name_taken                  | false                        |
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4443680Z +-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4443920Z 
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4444550Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:45.44]: Starting login with user 'xxx@xxxx.com'
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4597950Z Reading keychain entry, because either user or password were empty
2020-09-22T13:32:45.4598790Z Loading session from environment variable
2020-09-22T13:32:45.6175290Z Session loaded from environment variable is not valid. Continuing with normal login.
2020-09-22T13:32:49.4705060Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:49.47]: Successfully logged in
2020-09-22T13:32:49.4706080Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:49.47]: Fetching profiles...
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4141060Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.41]: Verifying certificates...
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4149150Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.41]: [36m$ security list-keychains -d user[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4311770Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.43]: â–¸ [35m    "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db"[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4313700Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.43]: [36m$ security find-certificate -c 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4594180Z security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4607740Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.46]: [36m$ security list-keychains -d user[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4762000Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.47]: â–¸ [35m    "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db"[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.4800050Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:50.47]: Installing WWDR Cert: curl -f -o /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/AppleWWDRCA20200922-8204-taekwn https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer && security import /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/AppleWWDRCA20200922-8204-taekwn -k /Users/runner/Library/Keychains/xxxxx-db
2020-09-22T13:32:50.6652730Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.66]: â–¸ [35m1 certificate imported.[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:50.6653850Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:50.66]: â–¸ [35m100  1062  100  1062    0     0  10948      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11062[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.0411770Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.04]: [32mFound 1 matching profile(s)[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.0412840Z WARN [2020-09-22 13:32:51.04]: [33mxxxxing provisioning profile...[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.0447160Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.04]: [32mSuccessfully xxxxed provisioning profile...[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.1782860Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.17]: Installing provisioning profile...
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2818580Z [32m/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/InHouse_com.xxxx.xxxx.mobileprovision[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2819590Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: Setting Provisioning Profile type to 'enterprise'
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2825490Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: /Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/InHouse_com.xxxx.xxxx.mobileprovision
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2834470Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: /Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/InHouse_com.xxxx.xxxx.mobileprovision
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2843330Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: 0b9001dc-643b-42bd-9790-1ea3cfbffe01
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2851860Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: com.xxxx.xxxx
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2860510Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: enterprise
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2869030Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: [32m------------------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2869900Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: [32m--- Step: install_provisioning_profile ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2870700Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: [32m------------------------------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:51.2871490Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.28]: Installing provisioning profile...
2020-09-22T13:32:51.3882450Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.38]: -------------------Running build --------------------
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1574740Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.38]: workspace path: /Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/xxxxx.xcworkspace
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1578940Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.46]: [32m-----------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1582840Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.46]: [32m--- Step: build_app ---[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1584120Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.46]: [32m-----------------------[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1585140Z WARN [2020-09-22 13:32:51.65]: [33mResolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:52.1586580Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:51.65]: [36m$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace xxxxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxxxx[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:54.8795920Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:54.87]: â–¸ [35mresolved source packages: [0m
2020-09-22T13:32:54.8949530Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:54.89]: [36m$ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace xxxxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxxxx[0m
2020-09-22T13:32:57.5897710Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.58]: Parsing project file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/xxxxx.xcodeproj' to find selected provisioning profiles
2020-09-22T13:32:57.5898790Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.58]: Finding provision profiles for 'Release'
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6479270Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: Merging provisioning profile mappings
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6480550Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: -------------------------------------
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6481340Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: Primary provisioning profile mapping:
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6482190Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: {"com.xxxx.xxxx"=>"com.xxxx.xxxx"}
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6482980Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: Secondary provisioning profile mapping:
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6483850Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: {:"com.xxxx.xxxx"=>"xxxx xxxx xx"}
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6484620Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: Resulting in the following mapping:
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6485420Z DEBUG [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: {:"com.xxxx.xxxx"=>"xxxx xxxx xx"}
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6486380Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:57.64]: Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.xxxx.xxxx"=>"xxxx xxxx xx"}
2020-09-22T13:32:57.6982110Z 
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7021850Z +------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7023820Z |                                                                          [32mSummary for gym 2.160.0[0m                                                                           |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7025060Z +------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7025830Z | workspace                                                        | xxxxx.xcworkspace                                                                           |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7026970Z | output_name                                                      | xxxx_2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24_SPRINT_12                                                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7027730Z | output_directory                                                 | /Users/runner/work/1/a                                                                                  |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7028900Z | export_options.manifest.appURL                                   | http://xxxx.xxxx.com/release/xxxx/ios/xxxx_2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24_SPRINT_12.ipa |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7030110Z | export_options.manifest.displayImageURL                          | https://xxxx.xxxx.com/release/product-qa/ios/Test/xxxxPush57.png                            |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7031380Z | export_options.manifest.fullSizeImageURL                         | https://xxxx.xxxx.com/release/product-qa/ios/Test/xxxxPush512.png                           |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7032160Z | export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.xxxx.xxxx | xxxx xxxx xx                                                                                  |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7033350Z | export_method                                                    | enterprise                                                                                              |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7034380Z | scheme                                                           | xxxxx                                                                                       |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7035190Z | destination                                                      | generic/platform=iOS                                                                                    |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7036380Z | build_path                                                       | /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-22                                               |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7037200Z | clean                                                            | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7037920Z | silent                                                           | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7038720Z | skip_package_ipa                                                 | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7039440Z | skip_package_pkg                                                 | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7040220Z | result_bundle                                                    | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7041000Z | buildlog_path                                                    | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                                                                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7041730Z | skip_profile_detection                                           | false                                                                                                   |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7042830Z | xcode_path                                                       | /Applications/Xcode_11.1.app                                                                            |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7044010Z +------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7044430Z 
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7058540Z +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7060120Z |                                                                             [32mGenerated Build Command[0m                                                                              |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7061350Z +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7062200Z | Option                                                                                                                                                    | Value                |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7063360Z +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7064600Z | set -o pipefail &&                                                                                                                                        |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7065370Z | xcodebuild                                                                                                                                                |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7066870Z | -workspace xxxxx.xcworkspace                                                                                                                  |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7068040Z | -scheme xxxxx                                                                                                                                 |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7069290Z | -destination                                                                                                                                              | generic/platform=iOS |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7070520Z | -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-22/xxxx_2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24_SPRINT_12\ 2020-09-22\ 13.32.57.xcarchive |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7071300Z | archive                                                                                                                                                   |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7072530Z | | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/xxxxx-xxxxx.log                                                                              |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7073310Z | | xcpretty                                                                                                                                                |                      |
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7074610Z +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
2020-09-22T13:32:57.7076500Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:32:57.70]: [36m$ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace xxxxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxxxx -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-22/xxxx_2019.1.4.xxxx.1.1.0.24_SPRINT_12\ 2020-09-22\ 13.32.57.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/xxxxx-xxxxx.log | xcpretty[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1794050Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:33:00.17]: â–¸ [35m[31mâŒ  error: No profile for team '8E6XXXXXX' matching 'xxxx xxxx xx' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '8E6XXXXXX/xxxx xxxx xx'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxx')[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1796870Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:33:00.17]: â–¸ [35m    [33mno rule to process file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/xxxxx/xxxx/zAFNetworking/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxx')[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1798670Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:33:00.17]: â–¸ [35m    [33mno rule to process file '/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/xxxxx/xxxx/zAFNetworking/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxx')[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1818450Z INFO [2020-09-22 13:33:00.18]: â–¸ [35m** ARCHIVE FAILED **[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1932450Z 
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1937320Z [31mâŒ  error: No profile for team '8E6XXXXXX' matching 'xxxx xxxx xx' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '8E6XXXXXX/xxxx xxxx xx'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxx')[0m
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1938410Z 
2020-09-22T13:33:00.1938530Z
```

Answer (score 1):

> Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '8E6XXXXXX/xxxx
> xxxx xx'

There are two directions that can be investigated.

**Direction 1:**

Please make sure the the private key `.p12` developer certificate in the key chain is match to the `.mobileprovision` file.

In general, `.mobileprovision` file has corresponding private key, which can be exported as `.p12` file from specific device. According to your log, the `.p12` developer certificate and the `.mobileprovision` file were installed into current environment successfully. But it still prompt the error `Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '8E6XXXXXX/xxxx xxxx xx'`.

So please first ensure the private key in the key chain is the one that match to the `.mobileprovision` file.

**Direction 2:**

The location your provision profile installed may be incorrect.

According to the log, the installed location of `.mobileprovision` is `/Users/runner/work/1/a/ios_artifacts/InHouse_com.xxxx.xxxx.mobileprovision`. But Fastlane searches for provision profile under the System: `/Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`. (The user our Hosted Mac agent used is `runner`)

As you can see, the search path Fastlane went through is not same with the installed location of `.mobileprovision`.

This thread [comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13365#issuecomment-443456460) has detailed explanation about that. You can refer to that.

Comment: Thanks  @Merlin Liang - MSFT , the think im doing it with fastlane ,

Comment: @user63898 is it possible for you to update with your pipeline definition and the complete log？

Comment: i added the pipeline ,added part of the log as text is to long

Comment: also can you please take alook at this question please :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023182/azure-pipeline-downloadbuildartifacts0-task-itempattern-cant-download-2-fi

Comment: @user63898 Please see my update. :-) Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Thanks i will check