# Azure pipeline : DownloadBuildArtifacts@0 task itemPattern , can't download 2 files with different file suffixs and name paternes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

im using DownloadBuildArtifacts@0 and i like to download all the *.ipa files and also the manifest.plist
file .
when writing : `itemPattern: '**/*.ipa`
it downloading me the ipa file
but when i do :

```
- job: copy_back_files_to_self_hosted_connect
  dependsOn: mac_agent 
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool: Default
  steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'Artifacts'
        itemPattern: '**/*.ipa|manifest.plist'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        Contents: '**/*.ipa|manifest.plist'
        TargetFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.FolderCompile}}'
```

it downloaded me none of the files not ipa and not the manifest.plist
what is the right pattern to download both all the time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Coming from your previous ticket....*

You need define your task as below format:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: Artifacts
    itemPattern: |
     **/*.ipa
     **/manifest.plist

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     **/*.ipa
     **/manifest.plist
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.FolderCompile}}'
```

Since `.ipa` and `manifest.plist` are all come from the build artifact: **Artifacts**, both of them are all under the **Artifacts** folder. So, please also do not forget to use `**/manifest.plist` to retrieve your needed files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'Artifacts'
    itemPattern: |
      **/*.ipa
      manifest.plist
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```